# Angular trouble with $http.get

Tags: angularjs, search, http-get

I just started learning Angular and I am having trouble retrieving data based on a http-get request. It works when I simply retrieve all movies, but not when I try to retrieve movies based on a search term (cfr. *search.html*). I hope someone can tell me where I went wrong, I really can't see it. Thank you in advance.

**app.js**:

```
var app;

(function() {

  app = angular.module('imdb', ['ngRoute']);

  app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/search', {
        controller: 'SearchController',
        templateUrl: 'views/search.html' 
      })
      .when('/movies', {
        controller: 'MovieController',
        templateUrl: 'views/movies.html' //works fine
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/movies'
      });
  });
})();
```

**SearchController.js**

```
(function (app) {

  app.controller('SearchController', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
    $scope.movies = [];

    $scope.searchMovie = function(title) {
      $http.get('https://angularbackend.azurewebsites.net/api/Movies/Search?title=' + title)
        .success(function(data) {
          $scope.movies = data;
        });
    };
  }]);
})(app);
```

**search.html**

```
<div>
  <form class="form" novalidate name="searchMovies" ng-submit="SearchController.searchMovie(title)" >
    <input type="text" ng-model="title" class="form-control" placeholder="enter title">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Search</button>
  </form>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>poster</th>
      <th>title</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies">
      <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried pasting `https://angularbackend.azurewebsites.net/api/Movies/Search?title=someTitle` into the browser to make sure your backend is responding correctly?

Comment: What excatly is not working? Do you get wrong data? Or is your APi call just not fired, do you get a 404 or is your title empty when making the call... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
SearchController.searchMovie(title)
```

by

```
searchMovie(title)
```

All expressions are always evaluated on the scope. So the first, incorrect one, will try to invoke the method searchMovie of `$scope.SearchController`, which doesn't exist.

Also note that success() is deprecated for quite some time now. Use then():

```
$http.get('https://angularbackend.azurewebsites.net/api/Movies/Search?title=' + title)
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.movies = response.data;
    });
```

You should also avoid using string concatenation to pass parameters. Those need to be encoded properly. So rather use

```
$http.get('https://angularbackend.azurewebsites.net/api/Movies/Search', {params: {title: title}})
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.movies = response.data;
    });
```